# Pause Javascript timer when the tab is not in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, timer, coffeescript

I have a requirement to show real time update of the number of people who did some action.
I implemented this functionality by making an ajax request to the server every 20 seconds.
But this ajax request happens even if the tab is not in focus/no one is looking at the update. Is there a way to figure out if the tab is active?

I have the following code(simplified version) and it doesn't work.

```
timer = undefined
$(document).ready ->
  timedCountUpdate()
  window.top.onblur = ->
    clearTimeout(timer)
  window.top.onfocus = ->
    timer = timedCountUpdate()

@timedCountUpdate = () ->
  timer = setTimeout(updateCountIndicator, 20000)

@updateCountIndicator = () ->
  $('.indicator').html = 100
  timedCountUpdate()
```

I still see the call being made every 20s even if i am not in the tab that has the app loaded. I am testing in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

In Coffeescript w/ jquery:

```
$ ->
  timeout_id = null

  resumeTimer = () ->
    # make ajax call here

    # Prevent multiple timers from operating simultaneously:
    clearTimeout timeout_id if timeout_id?

    # Recursive step (ideally fires in 'success' handler of ajax call)
    timeout_id = setTimeout(resumeTimer, 2000)

  $(window.top).focus () =>
    resumeTimer()
  $(window.top).blur () =>
    clearTimeout timeout_id

  # Start timer immediately:
  resumeTimer()
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled upon it in a Google search and wanted to provide another alternative that's better suited for what you're wanting to do.

The [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) is how these types of things should be done moving forward (or now IE10+). The API provides a `visibilityChange` event that triggers when the visibility of the tab changes.  In the callback, checking the `document.hidden` property will tell you whether the tab is hidden or not.

From there, clear your interval or start it back up again.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, i would do something like :

```
var tab_paused = false; // global

if (typeof window.top.onblur === 'function')
{
    window.top.onblur = function() {
     tab_paused = true;
    };
}
if (typeof window.top.onfocus === 'function')
{
    window.top.onfocus = function() {
     tab_paused = false;
    };
}
if (typeof document.onfocusout === 'function')
{
    document.onfocusin = function() {
     tab_paused = true;
    };
}
if (typeof document.onfocusin === 'function')
{
    document.onfocusin = function() {
     tab_paused = false;
    };
}

var ctx = setInterval(function() {
 if (tab_paused === false)
 {
  $('.indicator').html(100);
 }
}, 100);
```